# Accessing a Class which extends an AbstractClass which itself extends another Abstract Class

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I had a number of classes which extended an abstract class. Each of these classes could be returned in a 'set' by a method elsewhere in the project.

```
public abstract class AbstractBuilding{
    ....
}

public class ABuilding extends AbstractBuilding{
    ....
}
```

In another class:

```
World world = worldManager.getWorld();   
   for (AbstractBuilding building : world.getBuildings()){
       if (building.toString().contains("SomeSequence")){
            //Do Something
       }
    }
```

Where `world.getBuildings()` returns a set of all Abstract Buildings/classes.

Due to design changes, `ABuilding` is now an Abstract Class itself in addition to extending the original `AbstractBuilding`. And more classes extend from `ABuilding`. 
**Note:** I still have other regular classes which extend AbstractBuilding as before - `ABuilding2`

```
public abstract class AbstractBuilding{
    ....
}
public class ABuilding2 extends AbstractBuilding{
    ....
}

public abstract class ABuilding extends AbstractBuilding{
    ....
}

public class TheBuilding extends ABuilding{
    ....
}
```

When I call the `world.getBuildings` method now, I still get the set of all abstract buildings, which include buildings such as `TheBuilding` as it extends `ABuilding` which itself extends `AbstractBuilding`.

Is there some way that I can identify if a building in the returned set of buildings extends from this new abstract building?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking, but perhaps you're just looking for `instanceof`?

Comment: Specifically, `if (building instanceof ABuilding) ...`

Comment: The [Visitor](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor) pattern is typically recommended in this type of scenario.

Comment: You need `instanceof`, which means you should refactor until you don't.

Comment: `instanceof` does do what I want but the whole design pattern doesn't seem to be 'efficient'/correct. @jaco0646, I think this what I am looking for.

Comment: It seems that I will use `instanceof` and look into better ways of structuring scenario's such as this in the future

Comment: Also, you should consider _composing_ the building from (loosely-coupled) components, instead of _inheriting_ from many layers of abstract base classes. See also [Prefer composition over inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)